# Comparing Iterative Methods For and While

Tags: javascript

This first method works fine:

```
var hash = "#";
for (hash.length = 1; hash.length <= 7; hash += "#"){
  console.log(hash);
}
```

This method returns some strangeness:

```
var line = "#";
for(i = 0; i <= 7; i++) {
  while (line.length < i)
    line =+ "#";
  console.log(line);
}
```

Comment: "Returns some strangeness"? Please don't make us guess. Edit your question to describe the output you expect and the output you're getting.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You transposed your = and + it should be:

```
var line = "#";
for(var i = 0; i <= 7; i++) {
 while (line.length < i)
    line += "#";
  console.log(line);
}
```